# Sony A-7R (ILCE-7R) refuses to connect by Sony Remote API after firmware 2.0 update

Tags: sony, firmware, sony-camera-api, ssdp

The new fresh firmware 2.0 was released recently for my Sony Alpha 7R. I've updated the firmware just now. After that, applications that use Sony Remote API can't connect to the camera anymore. I've tried to oversee UDP traffic.
I see SSDP problem. An application sends SSDP request as it is requested by SDK, but receives no answer at all.

Update: I have to make some notes after a research. In case camera and computer Wi-Fi are idle for a bit (up to few MINUTES), connection is still possible, if it's requested after that idle period.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We don't expect any connection issues with the latest firmware and haven't heard any reports about it.

Couple things you can try:

1. Restart both the Camera and the computer.
2. If you have an Android device try connecting using that, perhaps it's something to do with connecting via your PC.
3. Also if you have an Android device, try using the latest version of Playmemories Mobile and see if you are able to connect without a delay.

Comment: Thank you so much. It looks like, maybe, too dirty radioenvironment, too much interference.

Comment: p.S. I had a hope the update will make some deal with the liveview problem (after liveview starting command is send through Remote API, any other commands have very bad chances to be received, including liveview stopping command and, that's a pity, shooting command). However, the problem is still there.